# How to handle empty dictionary while writing table with pyarrow

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I'm creating parquet file from python list of dictionary with `pandas` and `pyarrow`. But getting following error for empty nasted dictionary.

`Cannot write struct type 'subject' with no child field to Parquet. Consider adding a dummy child field`

code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

data =[
      {
       "name":"david",
       "subject":{}
     }
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pq.write_table(table, 'file1.parquet')
```

Answer (score 3):

Arrow is unable to guess the type of "subject" with the data you gave it (because it's empty). "subject" could be either:

- a [dictionary](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.map_.html#pyarrow-map)
- or a [struct](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.struct.html#pyarrow.struct).

In order to clear this ambiguity you need to provide an explicit schema to [Table.from_pandas](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.Table.html#pyarrow.Table.from_pandas) function:

```py
schema = pa.schema([
    pa.field("name", pa.string()),
    pa.field("subject", pa.map_(pa.string(), pa.string())),
])

table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, schema=schema)
```

But even with the schema it doesn't work becuase arrow expects the dictionary data to be represented as a list of tuples (instead of a dict):

```
data =[
    { "name":"david","subject": []},
    { "name":"john","subject": [("key1", "value1"), ("key2", "value2")]},
]

schema = pa.schema([
    pa.field("name", pa.string()),
    pa.field("subject", pa.map_(pa.string(), pa.string())),
])
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, schema=schema)
```